# .NET AntiXSS with Multiline Textboxes

Tags: .net, security, xss

I'm creating a web application where a textarea control sets the output of some text in another area of the site.  I want the user to enter text in paragraphs and these honoured in the output page (most likely with `<br />` tags).

Normally I'd just use the MS AntiXSS library for this and protect on input (and output for paranoia), however it's stripping out my line breaks.

I've been trying to create some extension methods to replace newlines with `<br />` tags and then sanitize, but this converts my `<br />` tags to `<br>` - I would prefer my application to render legal HTML (without another level of hacks of converting *after* the santize).

How can I render valid HTML and protect myself against XSS?

Comment: What I would do is to sanitize first and then replace newlines with br. If you are using ASP.NET MVC3, you could use a display template for the Multiline data type

Comment: If I sanitize first I have no newlines to replace.  I am using standard asp.net V3.5 not MVC