# preserving line spaces in asp .net not working

Tags: asp.net, razor

I am doing this to replace whitespaces and line breaks. The whitespaces part works however the line break does not.

It works if I removed the tags < > from the br. The line breaks in that case does get replaced by 'br'

I am using Antixss and sanitize.GetSafeHtmlFragment?

Is that causing a problem?

Comment: Yes, it is the Sanitize.GetSafeHtmlFragment that is removing the <br/> tag. Can someone please tell me how to include this tag in list of safe fragments. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work:

> http://wpl.codeplex.com/workitem/14053

```
AntiXss.GetSafeHtmlFragment(strMessage.Replace(ControlChars.Lf.ToString(),"<br>"))
```

> Where strMessage is the string with newlines you're calling AntiXss
>   on.

This might also help:

- http://eksith.wordpress.com/2012/02/13/antixss-4-2-breaks-everything/
- [.NET AntiXSS with Multiline Textboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9263311/net-antixss-with-multiline-textboxes)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little code....and a description of your current problem

Sounds like your doing this to a models field. In an edit or create view is this correct? if you are using texteditorfor(model => model.property) and the property is of type string then the line breaks will automatically be removed.

If it is a validation error due the HTML it should indicate that on the error page. If this is the case then in the model you must allow html with the [AllowHtml] attribute to the property. you must include system.mvc